# Restore iOS iCloud Backup via iTunes

Tags: ios, backup, itunes, icloud

I have a question concerning iOS backup-restore. Is there a way to restore an existing iCloud Backup, that I made, via iTunes and not directly over Wifi?

And vice versa. Can I make an backup via iTunes and save it as an iCloud backup or can iTunes only store backups locally?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

-regard you first question you can restore previous backup from iTunes ,there is not need of wifi 
-Step 1 - connect your phone with iTunes choose ->you's iphone 
-Step 2 - choose backup --> click on Restore Backup
- step 3 -> 
    Find My iPhone must be turned off before “your's iPhone” can be    restored.Go to iCloud,
    Settings on your iPhone and turn off Find My iPhone before restoring your iPhone.
-Step 3 ->
   Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8 back up the iPhone files here:
   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup,

Mac OS X your iPhone files are backed up at the following location:
   ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/
-step 4 - finish your restoration